# How to redirect URL when php get string is in current url

Tags: javascript, php, html, url, redirect

Here is my HTML button:

```
<button class="button-brightgreen" onclick="cancelbutton();">Cancel</button>
```

Here is my JavaScript redirect:

```
function cancelbutton() {
    var cancelURL = 'http://localhost:51937/php/searchUsers.php';
    $(location).attr('href', cancelURL);
}
```

This is on my editUser.php page. This code works fine for me, except when there is a php GET string in the current URL such as *?user_id=19*

When there is a GET in the URL and I click the cancel button, it takes me back to the same page (editUser.php) and displays *""*

How can I get the redirect to work when there is a GET in the current URL?

Comment: try like `javascript: window.history = "http://localhost:51937/php/searchUsers.php"`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured my problem out. The button was inside a form and when clicked, it would submit the form and the "" was coming from my PHP page. Taking the button out of the form, fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the string `user_id` is present in the current URL, if present then redirect.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('user_id=') > -1) {
    window.location.href = 'newURL';
}
```